# 404 Error, trying to add app.js

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access my .js file from an index.  Simple!

But the 404 Error I'm getting shows that the file is being searched for as

```
GET http://localhost:3000/app.js
```

instead of just "app.js" in the same folder as the index.
Not sure why it's adding the localhost path.

Here's my script link:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

which should be pretty straightforward?

Folder structure is:

```
|-ROOT FOLDER
-server.js
-package.JSON
   |-MODELS
        -article.js
        -notes.js
   |-PUBLIC
         -index.html
         -app.js
```

Comment: Please update your question with folder structure.

Comment: Do you have a `<base>` tag in the index?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you didn't write `src="/app.js"`

Comment: Do confirm you server is working on port 3000

Comment: @Himal Unless his server is case-insensitive, like Windows or OS X.

Comment: Server is up on 3000, yes.

Comment: @FarhanYaseen If the server weren't up, how would he have loaded the index page in the first place?

Comment: @himal everything is lowercase, they just auto-capitalized here in the forum

Comment: How do you access `index.html`? Is it just by `http://localhost:3000`?

Comment: @31piy I access it from server.js, this route:    app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/index.html');
});

Comment: @31piy oh, yes, for now just using http://localhost:3000 to access

Comment: @barmar yes, I tried it both with and without the slash, but originally it was without...

Comment: What is the URL of the index page? Maybe you're using a rewrite rule to rewrite it into the folder, but the rewrite rule doesn't apply to `app.js`.

Comment: If the rewrite happens on the server, the browser doesn't know about it, so it won't look for `app.js` in that folder.

Comment: @Barmar - I definitely suspect a rewrite rule hiding between. This question cannot be solved without further details.

Comment: @31piy Are there any simple ways to search for a rewrite rule?  I didn't knowingly put one in, but some of this is built with code provided by the class I'm in...

Comment: @barmar the URL for now is just localhost:3000

Comment: Then `localhost:3000/app.js` is the correct URL. Since there's no directory in the `app.js` URL, it uses the same directory as the URL for the index page.

Comment: @barmar okay, so it's not finding the file for a different reason then?

Comment: if anyone wants to poke around more deeply, all the files are up here: https://github.com/nicktamburro/NewsScraper  thank you for all your ideas!

Comment: It's not finding the file because there's no rewrite rule for `app.js` like there is for the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with your `server.js` I don't see any mapping for serving all the contents under `/public` folder. That's why the server returns 404 for the content inside it (the JS file in your case).

Try changing this statement:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'public/index.html');
});
```

to this:

```
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

This will automatically serve `index.html` on visiting the root path as well.

Comment: Works perfectly now! (after I installed and required "path").  Thank you @31piy !

Answer (score 0):

Try `src="./app.js"`. This might solve the problem.

Comment: It shouldn't. `.` means the current folder, which is the default if the link doesn't have a path.

Answer (score 0):

Please put your `js` and `index.html` file in root folder may be it will works. 
I don't know why is not working in this structure.

```
|-ROOT FOLDER
       |js  
       |-MODELS
            -article.js
            -notes.js
       |-Other-js-file
       -index.html
       -app.js
    -package.JSON
```

Comment: Why did you edit the question to show this structure?

Comment: sorry by miskate.